How to find dead code in a cargo workspace?
Rust will helpfully warn you if you have non-public functions or other items that are never used in the crate. This is great when developing a single crate, but has issues when you split your program up in multiple crates in a workspace.
Is there a way to automatically find dead code across multiple crates in a workspace? Ideally I'd be able to mark one crate in the workspace as a 'main' crate, and then every item which does not end up (indirectly) being used in the main crate (even if it is pub) is warned about as being unused.

I don't think Cargo can detect code that is dead only from the perspective of a single crate. If something is pub that means it could be consumed by some other project Cargo has no idea even exists. If you never intend to import that code from another crate than your 'main' crate or make it publicly available, why not just have them be modules instead of stand-alone crates?

@isaactfa Splitting your project into several crates in a workspace provides various benefits, like cleaner separation and significantly improved compilation times, and is commonly done for larger projects. (My scenario is an existing project with 300K+ lines of Rust code.) Either way I'm not really interested in arguing about it, or further justifying my scenario, please take it at face value.

Then I'm afraid the answer there's no way to do it with vanilla Cargo. I don't even think that something like pub(workspace) would be feasible because a workspace isn't really a language-level construct like a crate. Clippy isn't set up to do workspace-wide analyses like that either afaik.
